# Seeing cost data in analytics reports

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I've created a Custom Data Uploader script
which is uploading data to my google analytics profile.

I can see it's working and its uploading the file. I can see it on the "Custom Definitions" Tab in the Profile page. (Second picture on the link I attached).

But I cant see the data on the reports.
I tried to look under Traffic Sources -> Overview, it should be there from what I thought.

Where can I find this data in the reports?

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/platform/features/cost-data-import

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *Traffic Sources > Cost Analysis* report should contain your data, but it can take 12 hours for the data on a new feed to show up. However, I've found that subsequent loads are usually much faster.